# How to compact this for?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries. I want to count how many of those dictionaries has element "status" set to "connecting".

This is my working code:

```
connecting = 0
for x in self.servers:
    if self.servers[x]["status"] == "connecting": connecting += 1
```

Is there any way of compacting this? I was thinking something like:

```
connecting = [1 if self.servers[x]["status"] == "closed" else 0 for x in self.servers]
```

But it just returns a list of 0 and 1, doesn't add that 1 to connecting, which is what I expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a generator expression within `sum` function :

```
sum(x["status"]=="connecting" for x in self.servers.values())
```

Note that since the result of `x["status"]=="connecting"` is a boolean value and if it be True python will evaluated it as 1, so in the end it will returns the number of dictionaries that follows your conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum` for this. You have the list comprehension already, so just wrap it in `sum`.

```
connecting = sum(1 for x in self.servers if self.servers[x]["status"] == "closed")
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you wanted to count all the status types:

```
import collections

statuscounts = collections.Counter(server['status'] for server in self.servers.values())

connecting = statuscounts['connecting']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
connecting = len([1 for i in self.servers if self.servers[i]["status"] == "connecting"])
```

I used `len` as it has complexity O(1) vs `sum` that has complexity O(n) cause summing a list of just `1` is the same as getting it's length

Comment: You still have the O(n) complexity of building the list in the first place, so this isn't any faster than using `sum`.